# Chrome only browser warning my https request is 'Not Secure'. Why?

Tags: azure, https

I have a url to my Azure B2C login policy 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/bookssorted.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_bookssortedAuthenticationPolicy/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?local=signup&csrf_token=ZzZudlVmWWwvQ1BFeWswcFNVRlp2L01kcXM1YXlFRXFZblJub1NVaUpRVFBKSTlRZnQ5WWlXRFIvUEdkRlF3SjcxYyttaXJDS3FaSmhkNHhPL2V5R1E9PTsyMDE3LTA0LTI2VDA5OjM1OjU5LjQ3NjEzMTlaOzJ2bVBmdWI4YUlFSWZOMkNkT2Y5VFE9PTt7Ik9yY2hlc3RyYXRpb25TdGVwIjoxfQ==&tx=eyJUSUQiOiI3NTg2OThkOS02YjgwLTQzMDMtYTlkNy1lYjkyNTBkNjNiNWQifQ&p=B2C_1_bookssortedAuthenticationPolicy

and all the requests are using HTTPS but chrome says 'Not Secure' when all other browsers say it is fine. Why?

[image: chrome]
[image: firefox]

Answer (score 0):

There was a cookie called stsservice which was being sent using http. I closed the browser and loaded the url again and it worked. Hope this helps somebody